# privileges/new-user page update needed

Tags: bug, status-completed

[This page](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/privileges/new-user) needs a small update. The second bullet down should by changed to say "post more than two links" instead of "post more than one".

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the best way to point this out. I didn't know any other way though.

Comment: sorry, I meant to put this in meta, thanks for fixing.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I made this change on the "base" wiki at meta.SO; it will be propagated network wide soon.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/new-user